# segfault when calling QTableWidgetItem::text()

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qtablewidgetitem

I'm having troubles with a QTableWidget. I'm trying to get data from the QTableWidget when the user have changed a cell. So I'm using a

```
QObject::connect(ui->tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int,int)), this, SLOT(checkPoints(int,int)));
```

Here is the code of checkPoints

```
void MainWindow::checkPoints(int x, int y)
{
    QTableWidgetItem* item = ui->tableWidget->item(x,(1-y));
    if(!item || item->text().isEmpty())
    {
    }
    else
    {
        ajouterPoint(x);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a segFault when I'm calling item->text() and my app is crashing. I've checked x=0 and 1-y=1. I've already checked some posts about similar problems and it seems to be caused by the focus. But I don't really know what to do there.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It should be `if(!item && item->text().isEmpty())` instead. And why you use `1-y` and not `y`?

Comment: @vahancho `if(!item && item->text().isEmpty()` would make it access invalid pointer. That would check if the item is null, and if it is, it will try to access the `text` member.

Comment: 1-y cause my QWidgetItem has 2 columns and I want to check the other cell on the same row than the one I've modified. So if I'm selecting column 1, I'll check 1-y=0 and if I'm selecting column 0, I'll check column 1-y=1.

Comment: @vahancho: this code is working well when I'm reading the whole table using    
while(!((!itemX || itemX->text().isEmpty()) && (!itemY || itemY->text().isEmpty())))
    {
        i++;
        itemX = ui->tableWidget->item(i,0);
        itemY = ui->tableWidget->item(i,1);
    }

Comment: this problem isn't solved :/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't changed anything but it's working now. It looks like it's the correct way to do it. Maybe the problem came from somewhere else in my code that I've changed (I just put that part as comment during my modifications).